# Using moment js to show the date and time in datepicker but the date is keep on changing

Tags: angular

To show the date and time iam using the moment js .(dont know much about moment js), i was looking for the solution to show the date and time , at that time  i found the code from 
[How to I get current time from angular material Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563356/how-to-i-get-current-time-from-angular-material-date-picker).
Im facing the problem that time is continuosuly changing and also showing the error.since im new to the angular i dont know what the exact problem is.
html

```
 <mat-form-field class="date" (click)="createAt.open()">
                  <input [ngModel]="date" (ngModelChange)="onDataChange($event)" matInput [matDatepicker]="createAt" autocomplete="off" formControlName="createAt" placeholder="Date"
                    [value]="createAt" > 
                  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="createAt"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #createAt></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
```

ts

```
 date:Date;
   this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    createAt: [new Date()],
    });
 onDataChange(newdate) {
    const _ = moment();
    const date = moment(newdate).add({hours: _.hour(), minutes:_.minute() , seconds:_.second()})
    this.date = date.toDate();
    // console.log({hours: _.hour(), minutes:_.minute() , seconds:_.second()})
  }
```

Can anyone give the solution for this, or can anyone give solution to get the time .[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

use something like this... you have to format your date and time to print in specific format

```
moment().format('HH:mm:ss'); //it gives you the current time
```

Comment: in your code its not showing any where that you import moment First import moment at first of your page `import * as moment from 'moment'`

Comment: i tried those things ,but unfortunately it is not working

Comment: as per screen shot i guess you want current date on a Date inputbox right?

Comment: @ No not a current date , whatever the date we want to  select,but if we select the current date ,time also works .